# Effects of Git revert on undoing merged & deleted branches

Tags: git, version-control, git-revert

If I merged a branch with `master` branch with normal merge & not fast-forward merge. Then I deleted the branch merged. At a later stage I want to `revert` back to a commit before merging the two branches. Will git let me do it if there are no conflicts. If yes then will it bring back the deleted branch?

Comment: Short answer is no, it would not bring back the deleted branch.

Comment: The thing is that *revert* doesn't actually remove revisions from the history of the branch as it is before you start reverting. It **adds** revisions that remove changes introduced in previous revisions so the history of the branch by the end of the _revert_ operation will still hold the merge, because the merge is never actually removed form the history of the branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you are asking if whether the branch (as in, a revision *pointer*) will be recreated after you deleted it, the answer is **no**. But I'm talking about the *pointer* here. So... just so that it's clear. Let's assume the branch that you merged was called **foo**. After you merged it, you did: **git branch -d foo**. Now branch foo(the *pointer*) is gone but the revision that it was pointing to is not deleted at all (actually, it's now part of your branch). So if you now start reverting up to a point before the merge, you won't see a branch named **foo** come back from the dead.

Comment: So my master branch pointer will shift to a commit before the merge and this will create a new commit. And the foo branch pointer will be there in history but none of the contents of the merge. Is all that Right?

Comment: Ok I get it. My revert will create a new commit which will remove the changes done in the specified commit. And none of the  history will be affected.